# subsetting matrix observations in R

Tags: r

I have a matrix x1 which is as follows

```
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 63 64 65 66 67
 0  0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 1  1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 2  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
77  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 3  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1
 4  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0
 5  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 6  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 7  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 8  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 9  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 10 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 11 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 12 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 13 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 14 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 15 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 16 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 17 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 18 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 19 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 63 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 64 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 65 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 66 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 67 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

There are some different combinations.

```
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 63 64 65 66 67
 0  0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 1  1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 2  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
77  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 3  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1
 4  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0
 5  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0

 6  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 .  . . . . . . . . . .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
 .  . . . . . . . . . .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
 .  . . . . . . . . . .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
 67 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

What I am looking for is a program that will subset this matrix x1 such that each unique combination is stored in a new matrix, for example, the first row in x1, should be stored in a new matrix y1.

The second unique combination (there are two rows with this combination)

```
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 63 64 65 66 67
 2  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
77  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

both these rows should be stored in a new matrix y2. The third unique combination should be stored in matrix y3 ....so on....all this should happen automatically based on the initial matrix x1.

Any advise on how to do this will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
  split(as.data.frame(x2),do.call(paste0,as.data.frame(x2))) #this keeps it as data.frame in the list
```

If you want to split the matrix based on the unique rows from `x1`. This will store as `matrix` in the list

```
lst <- lapply(split(1:nrow(x1),do.call(paste0, as.data.frame(x1))), function(i) x1[i,]) 
lst[[6]]
#   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 63 64 65 66 67
#2  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
#77 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: @Tyrone Williams Glad it helped.